# Group by and sum and then compute results based on maximum value in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to group by vendor and id and take the sum of total weight from the below table. After that for every "Vendor", I need to get the maximum "Weight" and get the corresponding "Id".

```
Vendor Id  Weight
 AAA   1   1234
 AAA   1   121
 AAA   2   5182
 BBB   1   311 
 BBB   1   9132
 BBB   2   108
```

First query gives the following result:

```
[ { Vendor: 'AAA', Id: '1', Total_Weight: 1355 },
  { Vendor: 'AAA', Id: '2', Total_Weight: 5182 },
  { Vendor: 'BBB', Id: '1', Total_Weight: 9443 },
  { Vendor: 'BBB', Id: '2', Total_Weight: 108 }, ]
```

Second query result would be as follows as for Vendor 'AAA', the maximum Total_Weight is "5182" and it belongs to "Id" = 2. Similarly for 'BBB', the maximum Total_Weight is "9443" and it belongs to "Id" = 1.

```
[ { Vendor: 'AAA', Id: '2'},
  { Vendor: 'BBB', Id: '1'} ]
```

For first part, I have the query as follows

```
select Vendor, Id, sum(Weight) as Total_Weight from table group by Vendor, Id.
```

Not sure how to modify this query to get the second part of the result. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A typical method would use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by vendor order by weight desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

In many databases, a correlated subquery with the right indexes has slightly better performance:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.weight = (select max(t2.weight) from t t2 where t2.vendor = t.vendor);
```

The right index is on `(vendor, weight)`.

Answer (score 0):

The below query will solve your problem:

```
SELECT Vendor, Id from
    (select Vendor, Id, max(Total_Weight) from 
        (select Vendor, Id, sum(Weight) as Total_Weight from table group by Vendor, Id) 
    group by Vendor
    )
```

The inner nested queries produce the sum followed by finding the maximum value of the total weight. The outer select then provide you with the desired output.

Comment: The second inner query does not work, it returns Id as "Undefined"

Comment: Hi @user3447653, It is working fine for me. Please change the "table" name in the query as yours and try.

Comment: http://tpcg.io/u8GX35nx
Check out the working code here.